# Setting OpenAPI spec version with openapi-generator-maven-plugin

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm generating an `openapi.yml` spec file from Java code. Generation works just fine with this Maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <output>${project.parent.basedir}/api-rest-api</output>
        <templateDirectory>
            ${project.parent.basedir}/api-rest-api/.openapi-generator/templates
        </templateDirectory>
        <generatorName>java</generatorName>
        <library>native</library>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-rest-api</artifactId>
        <artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>
        <apiPackage>${project.groupId}.core.api.api.rest.endpoints</apiPackage>
        <invokerPackage>${project.groupId}.core.api.api.rest</invokerPackage>
        <modelPackage>${project.groupId}.core.api.api.rest.model</modelPackage>
        <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
        <globalProperties>
            <skipFormModel>false</skipFormModel>
        </globalProperties>
        <additionalProperties>bigDecimalAsString=true,dateLibrary=java8,hideGenerationTimestamp=true,sortModelPropertiesByRequiredFlag=false,useRuntimeException=true
        </additionalProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The input file is completely empty.

The beginning of the generated output file looks very cropped (no `info` and other openapi related stuff):

```
openapi: 3.0.1
paths:
# rest of the file...
```

**Question**: is it possible to set the info/version value in the output file so it looks like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
    version: 1.2.3
paths:
# ...
# rest of the file
# ...
```

So the version fits to the `project.version` value.

When I change the input file to contain the info/version value it is correctly passed to the output (as expected). But is it possible to do it more dynamically?

This option doesn't do it `<artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>`. It is used only as a version for a generated `pom.xml`